# PHP : $_SESSION empty after function execution

Tags: php, session

I started developing a platform mainly in php and sessions worked fine, until I stopped my Apache Server and started working on it a week later.

This is my problem :

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'backend/login.php';   // DB connect + functions           
    include_once 'menu.php';            // menu include
    check_logout();                     // check if user logged out
?>      
<?php
    include_once 'widgets/widgets.php'; // widgets : login, agenda, events, languages
    include_once 'footer.php';          // footer
?>
```

So basically these are the php parts of my page (the rest is HTML). backend/login includes login functions (and that file itself includes login to the DB followed by session_start()).

**home.php**

```
<?php
        include_once 'backend/login.php';           // connect to DB, login functions
        include_once 'backend/load_feed.php';       // feed functions           
        include_once 'menu.php';                    // include main menu
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>");
        </script>
        <?php           
        check_login();                              // ensure user is logged in
    ?>
```

When the login on index.php (form is hidden in widgets/widgets.php) is valid. It changes the window.location to *home.php*. The problem is that $_SESSION doesn't contain the information stored during the login.

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
/*
remote script used to conenct to the database
*/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "DB";

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check connection
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
}
session_start();
?>
```

This is the script used to connect to the database, it functions properly (I am able to verify the validity of the user credentials)

**Complementary Info :** 
 - I have verified that all info stored is stored in $_SESSION when logging in. (information is present in the scope of the function).
 - All files needing $_SESSION do include (directly or trough other includes) the *dbconnect.php* file, hence giving access to $_SESSION.
 - No output is generated before calling session_start();

Does someone have any idea of what might be the source of my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'backend/login.php';
    include_once 'menu.php';
    check_logout();
    include_once 'widgets/widgets.php';
    include_once 'footer.php'
?>
```

Try This!

I Hope This works & also do one thing, the list of files you have included above please make sure that you haven't called session_start() again in that files also, actually it doesn't matter but still give a try.

Also as you are saying that the function is giving problem, please also post the snapshot of the error so that it would me more helpful to understand the error.

Comment: I tried ! It doesn't seem to work..

The function has no problem at all, it uses $_SESSSION without any problem. In fact, index.php has perfect access to $_SESSION, but somehow home.php has none of it ..

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?>  //place this function at the very first line in your home.php file after opening the <?php tag and give it a shot.

Comment: That's what I just tried, but somehow by adding and removing a line, the session seems to be active again (without session_start() being used). I don't understand what just happened, bu thanks though ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first call session_start() according to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) but I am not quite sure

Comment: I already tried, but doesn't change anything. And as session_start() is called at the end of dbconnect and is included trough the other includes, I imagine the result is the same..

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `session_start()` function on beginning of the `home.php` and try again.

Comment: Doesn't work (it was one of the first things I tried of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can to try to add `sesion_start();` 
 in the top of the document before include files.